# SpriteKit animation not executed reliably

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm working on an iOS game based on SpriteKit/Swift using xCode, currently experimenting around with animations.

I've created a class `PlayerSprite` as a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and defined a method `moveRight` running the following action:

```
    run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: 32.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.25), completion: {
            debugPrint("Action completed.")
        }
    )
```

There's only one player instance of class `PlayerSprite` which is part of the node tree (SKScene -> SKTileMap -> PlayerSprite). The point is, that the mentioned action is not executed reliably:

1. When I start the app "for the first time" it's executed.
2. When I stop the app and start it again it's NOT executed.
3. When I press "pause" in the debugger and than "play" again, the action is executed!

This holds for the simulator as well as for starting the app on a connected iPhone. Stopping the app refers to pressing the stop button in xCode and starting to running it again from xCode.

The update loop is part of the `SKScene` subclass (called `LevelSceneView` in this case) and looks like this (just playing around so far):

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    debugPrint("Update called")

    if !player.hasActions() {
        player.moveRight()
    }

}
```

The update loop is called correctly, but the action is not executed (according to the log console).

Has anyone experienced such a behavior yet? Any ideas would be very much appreciated. I hope I've described the issue adequately. In case of any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I use the animation code and did not see the same problem. How did you setup the update loop? Could you share some codes so we can find the problem. BTW, what the meaning of stop? just press home button or run the app from Xcode again?

Comment: Added my answers inline, as it's not possible to format them within a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So If I understand correctly, the animation doesn't always run? I did run into a problem like this a while ago using xCode 9. The way I fixed it was to toggle the isPaused properties of the scene. So at the end of my update call I have two lines of code that read like so:

```
self.isPaused = true
self.isPaused = false
```

This way each time update() is called the scene is paused then paused. Using this I have never had a problem with running animations since. Hopefully, that helps get around the problem.

Comment: This solves the problem! Thanks a lot! But it's "just" a workaround... What's the root cause? I already suspected the scene to be paused - but that's no the case. I double checked this again, by printing out the status before putting in your code... So - if anyone has got an idea about the root cause? I'd like to remove the workaround later on.

Comment: One idea/hint: On another branch animations work fine without the workaround mentioned above - but on that branch I'm not subclassing `SKSpriteNode`, but move the sprite from the controller part of my code. I'm currently working on the view part and am thus refactoring the code.

Comment: Yeah its definitely just a work around. Your idea may be the answer as to what the root cause is; unfortunately I have never been able to figure out the cause myself. When I was given advice about the problem I was told that it was "a bug in xCode, and that Apple needs to fix it". But that just sounds like a lazy, "who cares" sort of answer to me. Maybe someone smarter than me knows what's really going on.

Comment: I just found out, that the TileMap is paused when the app is started (for whatever reason). Setting `isPaused` for the TileMap to false solves the issue, so that the workaround is not needed anymore. I'll dive into this in a couple of days (need to stop for now). However, the TileMap is holding the actual level data, loaded from a sks file and embedded using a `SKReferenceNode`.

Comment: Amazing. I do wish we knew the real reason why… but I'm just glad to suddenly have my SKActions animating properly again!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your animation located?

If it's in `didMove` function then your action is going to run only when your app is loaded/loading.

I think the problem could be that when you stop your app it's going to stay in phone memory for some time.

That will probably cause the problem, I would recommend to do **not** put any kinds of actions in `didMove` function if it's possible.

Comment: The `moveRight()` function (and thus the animation) is currently called within the update loop of the scene, that is, it's not called within `didMove`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the simple subclass from the SKSpriteNode and found no issue. Maybe you can restart from here.

```
class MySpriteNode: SKSpriteNode {

func moveRight(){
    run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: 3, y: 0.0, duration: 0.25), completion: {
            debugPrint("Action completed.")
    }
    )
  }
  }



       import SpriteKit
        import GameplayKit

        class GameScene: SKScene {

        //    private var label : SKLabelNode?
        //    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?
         private var myNode : MySpriteNode?



        override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
            // Called before each frame is rendered
            debugPrint("Update called")

            if !(myNode?.hasActions())! {
                myNode?.moveRight()
            }

        }


        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            myNode = MySpriteNode.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200))
            self.addChild(myNode!)
            }}
```

Comment: Actually my class `PlayerSprite` doesn't do much more than that yet. I don't think there's anything wrong with it but that the problem is rather node tree related or stuff like that. However it's strange. Thank you so far.

Comment: I also add the original gameScene. Hope it can help you.